# View not moving with finger with onTouchListener

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener, motionevent, ontouch

I'm trying to make a `View`'s x value move along with a finger as it drags across the screen. Although the view moving is smooth, it only moves ~1/3 of the distance that the finger does. The `View` in my case happens to be a `RecyclerView`, but I think this is irrelevant to the problem. What am I doing wrong in the following implementation?

```
view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(200);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (event.getHistorySize() < 1) break;
                final float latestX = event.getX(),
                        secondLatestX = event.getHistoricalX(event.getHistorySize() - 1),
                        firstX = event.getHistoricalX(0),
                        secondX = (event.getHistorySize() > 1) ?
                                event.getHistoricalX(1) : latestX;
                final float firstY = event.getHistoricalY(0),
                        secondY = (event.getHistorySize() > 1) ?
                                event.getHistoricalY(1) : event.getY();
                // if initial change x is greater than y
                if (Math.abs(secondX - firstX) > Math.abs(secondY - firstY)) {
                    view.setX(messageList.getX() + (latestX - secondLatestX));
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

If the code needs some explanation:

- `firstX` is the first x value that the finger touched on the screen
- `secondX` is the second x value that the finger touched on the screen
  (as in, the next time `onTouch` was fired with `ACTION_MOVE`)
- `latestX` is the most recent x value of the finger
- `secondLatestX` is the second most recent x value of the finger
- All y variables are the
  same as their x counter-parts but in the y direction

Am I calculating the variables incorrectly? I cannot seem to find a logic issue in anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find any way to do this, I just decided to create my own library from the ground up. Here it is:

https://github.com/GregoryConrad/SlideDetector

Answer (score 0):

As from your Use-case what i can understand is you want to move the view based on your touch.

Check out my project Long press and Move the square in infinite View.

[ZoomIt](https://github.com/andor201995/ZoomIt)